# Spark Kafka Streaming gives Incompatible Jackson Exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jackson, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

This is the error that I am getting :

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream.<init>(InputDStream.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.<init>(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:127)
    at chirpanywhere.stream.classification.service.streaming.StreamingClassificationPipeline.createStreamAndTransform(StreamingClassificationPipeline.scala:69)
    at chirpanywhere.stream.classification.service.streaming.StreamingClassificationPipeline.streamAndUpdateMLModelCache(StreamingClassificationPipeline.scala:58)
    at chirpanywhere.stream.classification.service.streaming.StreamingClassificationPipeline.run(StreamingClassificationPipeline.scala:54)
    at chirpanywhere.stream.classification.service.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:10)
    at chirpanywhere.stream.classification.service.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.7.8
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:64)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:730)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream.<init>(InputDStream.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.<init>(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:127)
    at chirpanywhere.stream.classification.service.streaming.StreamingClassificationPipeline.createStreamAndTransform(StreamingClassificationPipeline.scala:69)
    at chirpanywhere.stream.classification.service.streaming.StreamingClassificationPipeline.streamAndUpdateMLModelCache(StreamingClassificationPipeline.scala:58)
    at chirpanywhere.stream.classification.service.streaming.StreamingClassificationPipeline.run(StreamingClassificationPipeline.scala:54)
    at chirpanywhere.stream.classification.service.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:10)
    at chirpanywhere.stream.classification.service.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Can someone please tell me what's the problem.

My build.sbt looks like this :

```
   val akkaHttpV = "10.0.0"
  val sparkV = "2.1.0"

 "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.17",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % akkaHttpV,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % akkaHttpV,
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.21",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkV,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkV,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkV,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkV,
    "com.github.blemale" %% "scaffeine" % "2.0.0" % "compile",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % sparkV ,
    "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.0-M3",
    "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.5.0" ,
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test",
```

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward. Which Jackson dependency are you compiling with, and which one is Spark using?

Comment: I have not added any jackson dependency ! Hence asked this question !

Comment: Try visualizing the dependencies with [SBT dependency graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) to see which dependency is consuming it.

Answer (score 2):

Exception is thrown by Jackson Scala module, when inspecting version of `jackson-databind` that is deployed with it. Scala module requires same minor version; in this case exception message is incomplete (it should include both versions) -- I am guessing you have newer `jackson-databind` (2.7.8 is a good recent version), and older Scala module, perhaps one Spark bundles (2.5.3?).

Scala module is quite cautious here as often "close enough" minor versions do work: but the solution is to ensure databind and Scala module have same minor version (and might as well same patch version too).

Comment: Good answer, but maybe a workaround (dependency override or else) would improve it